# Force read_xml to interpret string as literal XML

Tags: r, libxml2, xml2

I've been struggling to force the `read_xml` function (`xml2` package) to treat my character input as a literal string. Apparently, if the input doesn't look like XML enough, it will try to open it as an url, and also as a local file name. This freaks me out, even if it isn't an obvious security bug (but I can definitely see situations where it is). So, in short, how do I force the function to interpret my input as literal xml text, and disable the possibility of url/filename lookup?

I would prefer not to use the `XML` package, as it's apparently orphaned.

Comment: One trivial workaround would be to include an XML comment in your literal XML string (e.g. `paste0('<!-- -->', lit)`) but that’s obviously terrible. The function honestly isn’t great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to explicitly coerce your literal text to a `raw` value and call `read_xml` with that:

```
xml2::read_xml(charToRaw(lit))
```

Since that’s what `read_xml` does internally for literal XML strings anyway. However, lacking any tags `read_xml` will then *always* fail because it’s expecting at least one surrounding tag. But at least this will prevent `read_xml` from accidentally opening files.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source for `xml2:::read_xml.character`, it will tread the data as raw input if it contains any `<` or `>` symbols. Then it passes the value to `read_xml.raw`. You could write your own wrapper to make sure that always happens.

```
read_xml_literal <- function(x, ..., as_html=FALSE, options = "NOBLANKS") {
    if (length(x) == 0) {
        stop("Document is empty", call. = FALSE)
    }
    options <- xml2:::parse_options(options, xml2:::xml_parse_options())
    if (grepl("<|>", x)) {
        xml2:::read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., 
            as_html = as_html, options = options)
    } else {
        stop("Input does not '<' or '>'")
    }
}
```

So this works

```
read_xml_literal("<foo><bar /></foo>")
```

bit this does not

```
read_xml_literal(xml2_example("cd_catalog.xml"))
```